# ¿Estaria bien mi estructura PHP, o en un futuro causaria posibles errores?

Tags: php, formato, estructuras

Llevo un tiempo, aprendiendo php, y me he planteado crear un proyecto ya mas serio.

Aún estoy haciendo prototipos de estructurar el proyecto, y de momento, de todas las que he hecho, se basa en esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
ahora que habéis visto como es la imagen del prototipo, os expongo que hacce cada cosa.

> Se me olvido decir, que el diseño, es los tipicos de administración. 
>   Aqui un ejeplo --> https://www.google.com/search?q=admin+template&tbm=isch

---

### Archivos

> **Index.php** 
>   Este archivo, contiene la plantilla principal del proyecto: 
>   Scripts, css, etc (Basicamente la estructura del html)
>
> **Menu.php** 
>   Seria una simple lista

```
<ul><li><a href="#Pagina=Tareas">Tareas</a></li></ul>
```

> Ejemplo: **Tareas.php** 
>   Seria uno de los archivos de contenido

---

### Estructura de archivos

La estrcutura basica seria la siguiente:

- Assets (Recursos de diseño, scripts, imagenes, etc...)
  -> Main.js 
  -> Main.css 
  -> ...
- Contenido (Contenido de las paginas web)
  -> Index.php 
  -> Tareas.php 
  -> Ajustes.php 
  -> ...
- Uploads (Contiene todos los archivos subidos)
  -> img1.png
  -> Documento.docx
- Data (Contiene archivos de datos en formato json)
  -> Users.json
  -> Menu.json
  -> ...

NOTA: Todas las peticiones se realizan con ajax

### **Mi pregunta es:**

¿Podria darme errores esta estructura de archivos?

Comment: hola, aunque interesante tu pregunta; la misma es basada en opiniones y por ese motivo se sale de la temática del sitio, recuerda que la comunidad es para poder resolver problemas concretos de programación

Comment: Lo que busco son opiniones, ya que no se cuales paginas buscar para exponer este tipo de preguntas, y la unica que conozco es esta.

Comment: te daré un +1 para que acumules reputación, puedas entrar al chat y no contribuir a que te cierren la pregunta; espero con lo que le quite que es pedir opiniones recibas la ayuda que buscas

Comment: a este [chat] es el chat oficial de la comunidad

Comment: Creo que si esta bien hecho todo, me refiero a que cada estructura cumple con su tarea, entonces no vas a tener errores. Yo hago lo mismo y mi sistema de programación es muy simple. Uso pocas funciones y no uso objetos. Tampoco uso frameworks. Trabajo en bloques y cada bloque es independiente del otro. Ninguno genera errores, si tengo que actualizar uno, no me modifica el otro y así. Esa es mi manera.

Comment: @Ruben-PX Utiliza la misma estructura que usan los frameworks denominadas hoy en día **" buenas prácticas"** por ejemplo Symfony la misma que utilizó en mis proyectos [aquí tienes un ejemplo con discusión](https://symfony.es/noticias/2017/04/10/symfony-4-estructura-de-directorios/)

Comment: @Ruben-PX tal como te menciona el comentario anterior, puedes usar alguna estructura que usen algunos frameworks. Yo personalmente, uso MVC (modelo vista controlador) para generar las estructuras de mis proyectos. Tambien te recomiendo que te familiarices con estas estructuras, ya que cada vez, querras desarrollar aplicaciones mas grandes, ya sea por necesidad o gusto propio. saludos.

Comment: Es una buena estructura.